# Python SQLite Checking Conistency between file and database

Tags: python, sqlite

Situation: Given the below example,

```
  fileA                   databaseB
  | 1:abc:xyz |           | 1:abc:xyz |
  | 2:def:uvw |           | 2:def:uvw |
  | 4:jkl:opq |           | 3:ghi:rst |
  | 6:pqr:ijk |           | 4:jkl:opq |
  | 7:stu:fgh |           | 5:mno:lmn |
                          | 6:pqr:ijk |
```

Problem: I need to update `databaseB` to match `fileA`, both inserting new rows and deleting non-existing ones.

Question: How can this be done in SQLite statements, using Python?

Additional Information 1: I am already able to insert the non-existing ones by using `INSERT INTO OR IGNORE` SQL Statement. This will however, only add index 7 of fileA to databaseB, but not delete indexes 3 and 5.

Additional Information 2: Would it be easier to just delete the databaseB and create a new database using fileA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert, just use INSERT OR IGNORE (or maybe INSERT OR REPLACE).

To be able to know which rows are outdated, you need to collect all file IDs into a separate (temporary) table. Then execute:

```sql
DELETE FROM databaseB WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM fileA);
```

Comment: Just wondering, if I have say 2 million rows in `fileA`, and about 2 million rows in `databaseB`. Would it be faster to delete `databaseB` and create a new `databaseB` with the data in `fileA`?

Comment: Depends; you have to measure yourself.